# Stacking css pseudo-elements?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

what would be the best way achieving those nested square-elements, using as less markup as possible? I know :after/:before can not be stacked multiple times on the same element but what would be the best approach to a structure like this?

also im heaving difficulties recreating the shown structure (im using bootstrap4) in general. Flexbox doesn't seem to be the right approach? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What's the value of the white-ish background?  Is it textured?

Comment: @JosephMarikle, no its just plain white

Comment: Is there a particular need to use pseudo elements for the blue squares? Can't they just be images?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is definitely not a complete question without a demonstration of effort on your part; but it did look really fun, so I tried it anyway.  In the future please include any relevant code, particularly your attempt at solving the issue.  Regardless, here is what I was able to come up with: https://jsfiddle.net/8akxn0xn/.  I recommend running it through an auto-prefixer if you intend on using it in any kind of production environment though.

Comment: @JosephMarikle, great job, I like your approach.
thanks for your advice, ill make sure to include a few snippets on my next post

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap you could try something like this.

```css
.red {
border: 1px solid red;
}

.blue {
border: 1px solid blue;
}

.purple {
border: 1px solid purple;
}

.green {
border: 1px solid green;
}

div > div {
height: 100px;
}

div > div > div {
height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 red">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-4 blue">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 purple">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 green">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 purple">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!